# xrandr to set display to use single monitor, even if you have another monitor connected or disconnected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, x-windows, xrandr

xrandr to set display to use single monitor, even if you have another monitor connected or disconnected

I have a laptop that can move and be connected to different monitors etc through out the day.

I usually exit my windows manager and login again every time I disconnect, to have this done automatically for me.

I would like to stay logged in and use the same tool that does the auto-detection and set up or doing it using xrandr. I guess I am just unfamiliar with the different tools available.

1. With my work secondary monitor connected. I get the following.

> ```
> xrandr
> ```
>
> Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
>      LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
>         1366x768       60.0*+
>         1360x768       59.8     60.0
>         1024x768       60.0
>         800x600        60.3     56.2
>         640x480        59.9
>      DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
>         1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9
>         1680x1050      59.9
>         1600x900       60.0
>         1280x1024      75.0     60.0
>         1440x900       59.9
>         1280x800       59.9
>         1152x864       75.0
>         1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9
>         1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0
>         832x624        74.6
>         800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2
>         720x576        50.0
>         720x480        60.0     59.9
>         640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9
>         720x400        70.1
>      VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

2. If I unplug this monitor to move my laptop. I loose every thing on that screen. Its still running but I can see it.

> # xrandr
>      Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
>      LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
>         1366x768       60.0*+
>         1360x768       59.8     60.0
>         1024x768       60.0
>         800x600        60.3     56.2
>         640x480        59.9
>      DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      HDMI1 disconnected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
>      VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>        1920x1080 (0x49)  148.5MHz
>              h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
>              v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz

3. If I am already logged in I only see the output of the first monitor, even after connecting the second monitor.

> # xrandr
>      Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
>      LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
>         1366x768       60.0*+
>         1360x768       59.8     60.0
>         1024x768       60.0
>         800x600        60.3     56.2
>         640x480        59.9
>      DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>         1920x1080      60.0 +   50.0     59.9
>         1680x1050      59.9
>         1600x900       60.0
>         1280x1024      75.0     60.0
>         1440x900       59.9
>         1280x800       59.9
>         1152x864       75.0
>         1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9
>         1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0
>         832x624        74.6
>         800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2
>         720x576        50.0
>         720x480        60.0     59.9
>         640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9
>         720x400        70.1
>      VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>      VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've actually given a fairly good answer that I really can't match up. So, let me explain my use case for `xrandr`, in hoping that the next person might be able to benefit from us both.

Hopefully my use case for `xrandr` is a more common one. I plugged in my laptop to HDMI so that I can watch movies from my big TV, but my Xfce isn't giving me any option to turn my laptop's monitor (LVDS) off while watch movies on TV.

So I use

```
xrandr --output LVDS --off
```

to turn of my laptop's monitor (LVDS) off, in order to prolong its life. Then use

```
xrandr --output LVDS --auto
```

to bring it back after I've done watching movies.

That's my use case. In the case when you've unplugged the monitor from you laptop, but BADLY need to see the apps on the secondary monitor even without one, you can increase virtual X space and just panning with the mouse to there as explained [here](https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/panning-using-xrandr/). For you specific case, it can be:

```
xrandr --size 1366x768 --panning 3286x1080
```

It is doable but not practical, that why I emphasized on *"BADLY need"* :-)

Thanks for your 10 points

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any posts explaining how to use xrandr to get a single monitor working and figured it out by trail and error. 
To resolve issues the following command or combinations work.

1. With my work secondary monitor connected.

   To go down to a single monitor which ever is primary
   Get the resolution of that monitor
   `xrandr --size 1366x768`
   That takes me down to only my primary monitor even if the other monitor is still connected.
   The follow may also be useful.
   `xrandr --output HDMI1 --off`
2. If I unplug this monitor to move my laptop. I loose every thing on that screen. Its still running but I can see it.

   Or the same command as above
   `xrandr --size 1366x768`
3. If I am already logged in I only see the output of the first monitor, even after connecting the second monitor.

   `xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of LVDS1`
   That should resolve this problem, to get the second monitor working.
   IF it is still not displaying any thing on the second monitor
   `xrandr --size 3286x1080`

I did find that google-chrome lost its scaling for some reason and the whole interface be came unusable. This post helped me solve those issues
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473089

```
# xdpyinfo | grep -B 1 resolution
dimensions:    1366x768 pixels (869x285 millimeters)
resolution:    40x68 dots per inch
xrandr --dpi 96
```

Comment: Ha, you beat me, I figured it out by trail and error as well. *"If I unplug this monitor to move my laptop. I loose every thing on that screen. Its still running but I can't see it"*, if you really want to see them even  without the secondary monitor, check out https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/panning-using-xrandr/

Comment: @xpt, I can't accept my own answerers, and you blog is a pretty good answer. Please post some thing to get those 10 points from me.

Comment: In all my googleing, I could not find a link that answered my specific question. @xpt, if you have some more to add, I will defiantly appreciate it.